# How to add third state to checkbox?

Tags: angular, checkbox

Hi I am developing web application in angular. I am displaying checkbox with three states. I am distinguishing states usng css classes. The three states are cross-marked,check marked and blank. Below is the implementation part.

```
<div *ngIf="node.data.checked==true && node.data.allow==true">
    <label class="container">
        <input (change)="check(node, !node.data.checked)" type="checkbox" [indeterminate]="node.data.indeterminate" [checked]="node.data.checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
        {{ node.data.name }}
    </label>
</div>

<div *ngIf="node.data.checked==true && node.data.allow==false">
    <label class="container">
        <input (change)="check(node, !node.data.checked)" type="checkbox" [indeterminate]="node.data.indeterminate" [checked]="node.data.checked">
        <span class="checkmark xmark"></span>
        {{ node.data.name }}

    </label>
</div>

<div *ngIf="node.data.checked==false">
    <label class="container">
        <input (change)="check(node, !node.data.checked)" type="checkbox" [indeterminate]="node.data.indeterminate">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
        {{ node.data.name }}

    </label>
</div>
```

I am attaching UI image above.
[image: Tri state checbox]

Device model1 contains cross marked,device model2 contains check marked and devicemodel4 contains blank. These are three states. Now when user clicks on any one of the checkboxe's state should change in the below path.

```
blank --> checked --> cross --> blank
```

Above is circular path. For example, if the checkbox is checked then when the user clicks on it then checkbox should become cross and if the user clicks it again then blank and if the user clicks it again then again checked and so on. Displaying part i have done. Can someone help me to make this work as i said above? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/indeterminate/ for a basic guide on the indeterminate state

Comment: Thanks for your help. In javascript, we are sending checkbox using toggle(this). How can i do it in angular?

Comment: when you need a "circular" path use the "remainder" operator: cb.checked=(cb.checked+1)%3 give you the secuence 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [checkbox indeterminate state](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/indeterminate/) for this.

If you bind to the `change` event, you can pass the checkbox, like so

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="toggle($event.target)" />
```

You can then create the toggle function, like in the link above:

```
toggle(cb) {
  if (cb.readOnly) cb.checked = cb.readOnly = false;
  else if (!cb.checked) cb.readOnly = cb.indeterminate = true;
}
```

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfuzhu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: it works. thanks. But when binding data should i do like this? readonly="readonly"?

Comment: You should be able to bind using `[indeterminate]="true"` for example, as well using `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: When binding data to checkbox i have done something like this. I want to show intermediate state.  <input (change)="toggle($event.target)"
                                           type="checkbox"
                                           readonly />
                                    {{ node.data.name }} This is not working. May I know am I missing something?

Comment: Everything worked. Can we edit design of intermediate state using styles?

Comment: There is a `:indeterminate` psuedo selector in CSS, that may help. What is it you want to display?